# Angularjs setting checkbox to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set a checkbox to true with Angularjs. Right now I'm cheating using vanilla javascript to manipulate the DOM, but I want to do it the right way with Angularjs.

Here is the view:

```
<div x-ng-repeat="addon in addons">
  <label for="{{addon.addoncode}}">
    <input type="checkbox"  
    name="{{addon.addoncode}}" 
    value="{{addon.addoncode}}"  
    id="{{addon.addoncode}}"  
    x-ng-model="addon.checked" 
    x-ng-click="checkAddonDependencies()"  >
   <span x-ng-bind-html="addon.addon_desc">{{addon.addon_desc}}</span> </label>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
 if (document.getElementById(dep)) {
    document.getElementById(dep).checked=true;
     }
```

The dep value is equal to the addoncode value, so if it exists I check the box. This works and checks the box but how could I do this using the scope instead?

I tried:

```
x-ng-model="addon.addoncode"
```

with

```
$scope.addon.dep = true;
```

But no luck... any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple thing to do. Instead of using the checkbox id:

```
document.getElementById(dep).checked=true;
```

I just needed to use the angular filter:

```
var x = filterFilter($scope.addons, {
    addoncode: dep
});                 

x[0].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="addon in addons">
  <label for="{{addon.addoncode}}">
   <input type="checkbox"  
     name="{{addon.addoncode}}" 
     value="{{addon.addoncode}}"  
     id="{{addon.addoncode}}"  
     ng-model="addon.checked" 
     ng-click="checkAddonDependencies()"  >
  <span ng-bind-html="addon.addon_desc">{{addon.addon_desc}}</span> </label>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
function countController( $scope, $timeout )
{
$scope.addons = [
   {
       checked: true
   },
    {
       checked: false
   }
];   
}
```

see in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nww4/51/)</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

The main point of angular is you don't need to worry about to update HTML. you just need change your `$scope.addons`.

you can see how your code works with promises and how you add items every 3 sec to `$scope.addons`. I simulated async task by `delay` service.

<kbd>[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/486/)</kbd>

BTW, I didn't touch your HTML

Comment: But addons is already set: myService.addons().then(function (addons) {
        $scope.addons = addons;

Comment: well, i didn't know about , you use promises a.e. async methods, its other story

Comment: Thanks but I still don't have it. I don't want to push new texboxes into the scope.  I need to check the box that matches the value returned by my service.

Comment: well, this is direction I pointed, I think you have enough posted info ,  no one will read all your code and find the problem, but I did my best to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your object `addon` only exists inside the ng-repeat on your template. On the controller you should have something like:

```
$scope.addons[0].isChecked = true;
```

As addons is an array. Note that isChecked could take any property name

Then on the template use:

```
<div x-ng-repeat="addon in addons">
  <label for="{{addon.addoncode}}">
    <input type="checkbox" x-ng-model="addon.isChecked" x-ng-click="checkAddonDependencies()"  >
   <span x-ng-bind-html="addon.addon_desc">{{addon.addon_desc}}</span> </label>
</div>
```